# Why is <h3> acting like <a>

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website in which I have written a tag of h3 but is acting like a link to the page mentioned above. Here is the code:

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="sitename">
    <h2 style="color:white">Metro City</h2>
  </div>
  <ul class="bar">
    <li class="bar"><a class="bar" href="Home.html" />Home</li>
    <li class="bar"><a class="bar" href="Search.html" />Search</li>
    <li class="bar"><a class="bar" href="Buy.html" />Buy</li>
    <li class="bar"><a class="bar" href="Sell.html" />Sell</li>
    <li class="bar"><a class="bar" href="About Us.html" />About Us</li>
    <li class="bar"><a class="bar" href="ContactUs.html" />Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</div>





<div>
  <h3 style="color:black">Find your Home</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe because you never close any of your link tags?

Comment: Don't use inline styles, you're going to regret this decision someday. Use an external css file instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `<a>` tags are not self-closing. Essentially, your first `<a>` tag is not closed, so everything thereafter is treated as a child element by the browser.

You need to modify your markup to correctly close `<a>` elements as follows:

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="sitename">
        <h2 style="color:white">Metro City</h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="bar">
        <li class="bar"><a class="bar" href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="bar"><a class="bar" href="Search.html">Search</a></li>
        <li class="bar"><a class="bar" href="Buy.html">Buy</a></li>
        <li class="bar"><a class="bar" href="Sell.html">Sell</a></li>
        <li class="bar"><a class="bar" href="About Us.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="bar"><a class="bar" href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <h3 style="color:black">Find your Home</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Note the `style="color:black"` is probably not necessary after you've done that as most browsers default text to being black. (Unless you are applying other styles to the element).

Comment: Unless the OP has a CSS file that overrides it ;) (`h3 { color: red; }`, for example).

Comment: Actually, anchor elements cannot contain other anchor elements, so they will be closed automatically and will not be children of the first anchor.  Therefore, only the *last* anchor must be closed.  But it's certainly best practice to close each.

Comment: @RickHitchcock That rather assumes that the browser is built to standards ;)

Answer (score 0):

A couple things.

1. You didn't close the style in h3 with a semicolon (`;`). Change it to `<h3 style="color:black;"></h3>` **EDIT:** Not necessary for the last property.
2. You aren't closing your link tags. Fix them like this: `<li><a class="bar" href="Home.html"/>Home</a></li>`

Comment: There is no need for the `;` delimiter in this case. It is the last CSS declaration.

Comment: i don't think that the semicolon is necessary for the last property, but i might be wrong

Comment: @BenM I know this isn't needed, but I always put semicolons, even if there's just one. It's handy practice, and reduces the number of errors when typing CSS code!

Comment: I do the same, Lee... but I wasn't aware it wasn't needed on the last property.

Comment: @Lee Absolutely, my point was more to clarify that this wasn't the reason for the errors the OP was experiencing.

Comment: @BenM Ah I see in this person's answer. Got it.

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't suggesting that was the error. I was pretty sure it was the unclosed link tags, but I figured that could've caused extra issues later on. Glad to learn something.